# mySQL: Showing data from one table using id from another

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want my users to be able to make a favourite list.

I have two tables in a database in mySQL. One stores information about businesses and the other stores the unique user ids as well as the ids from the first table that the user has marked a favourite.

**Table 1**

```
<pre>
ID   | NAME | EMAIL      | PHONE    |
1    | Joe  | a@mail.com | 25634565 |
2    | John | b@mail.com | 43634565 |
3    | Jack | c@mail.com | 65634565 |
4    | James| d@mail.com | 43634565 |
5    | Julie| e@mail.com | 65634565 |
...
</pre>
```

Table 2

```
<pre>
  USERID   |  FAV1  |  FAV2  |  FAV3  | FAV...
2565325489 | 1      | 3      | 5      |
8596854785 | 3      | 2      | NULL   |
2356256263 | 5      | NULL   | NULL   |
...
</pre>
```

The output I want for a user (in this example the first in table2):

```
<pre>
Joe  | a@mail.com | 25634565 |
Jack | c@mail.com | 65634565 |
Julie| e@mail.com | 65634565 |
</pre>
```

I have looked into JOIN LEFT and minus query calls, but I just can't make it work. I have a basic understanding of mySQL and PHP, but not a lot.

I would highly appreciate any help with what approach to take.

Ps. If there are better ways to structures my databases, I would love to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a table with two fields - `userID` and `fav` - make one entry for each entry. And then...

`SELECT table1.name, table1.email, table1.phone FROM table1,table2 WHERE table2.fav = table1.id AND table2.userid = 2565325489`

Comment: Thank you, kuh-chan - this works, it's sounds simple to maintain and I understand the code behind. Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query('SELECT name,email,phone FROM t1 table1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.fav1');  

//iterate the results
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['name']." ".$row['email']." "$row['phone'];
}
```

Comment: I went with one of the other answers that was easier to understand for me, so I haven't given it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from table1 InnerJoin (Select * from table2) as t4 on table1.ID=t4.FAV1
```